# solve integral of $\frac{\sin (ax)}{ \sin(x)}$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, periodic-functions

I would like to find the area under the curve of $\frac{\sin(ax/2)}{\sin(x/2)}$, namely between the first zero crossing on the left and right:

$$
\int_{-\frac{2\pi}{a}}^{\frac{2\pi}{a}} \frac{\sin(\frac{ax}{2})}{\sin(\frac{x}{2})} 
$$

I realized from Wolfram Alpha that this was not a simple solution, so I was wondering if there is a good approximation for the area. For my application, $a$ is usually over $10000$.

Thank you for any advice and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using symmetry and the change of variable $x=2\,t$ we have
$$
\int_{-\frac{2\pi}{a}}^{\frac{2\pi}{a}} \frac{\sin(\frac{ax}{2})}{\sin(\frac{x}{2})}\,dx=
4\int_0^{\pi/a} \frac{\sin(a\,x)}{\sin x}\,dx.
$$
If $a>2$ then
$$
\frac{a}{\pi}\,\Bigl(\sin\frac{\pi}{a}\Bigr)\,x\le\sin x\le x\quad 0\le x\le\frac{\pi}{a}
$$
and
$$
\int_0^{\pi/a}\frac{\sin(a\,x)}{x}\,dx\le\int_0^{\pi/a}\frac{\sin(a\,x)}{\sin x}\,dx\le\frac{\pi}{a}\,\csc\frac{\pi}{a}\int_0^{\pi/a}\frac{\sin(a\,x)}{x}\,dx.
$$
Finally we get
$$
\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx\le\int_0^{\pi/a}\frac{\sin(a\,x)}{\sin x}\,dx\le\frac{\pi}{a}\,\csc\frac{\pi}{a}\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx.
$$
For $a$ large
$$
1\le\frac{\pi}{a}\,\csc\frac{\pi}{a}\le1+\frac16\,\frac{\pi^2}{a^2}.
$$
Thus
$$
0\le\int_0^{\pi/a}\frac{\sin(a\,x)}{\sin x}\,dx-\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx\le\frac16\,\frac{\pi^2}{a^2}\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I seem lack the mathematics to understand your derivation, could you possibly explain the solution (for example, how you arrived at the domain that sin(x) is larger than (a/pi)*sin(pi*x/a), or how that is applied to the original equation in the next line). Also, for the final equation, would it be correct to say that the upper limit of my integral, (1/6)*(pi^2/(a^2)) would be a good approximation to the actual area defined in this integral?

Comment: Look at the graph of $\sin x$ on the interval $[0,\pi/a]$. Since $\sin x$ is a convex function, its graph is above the chord. This gives the lower bound. A good approximation of your integral is $4\int_0^\pi \sin x/x\,dx$. The error is less than $4\,\pi^2/(6\,a^2)$.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating, but sorry, I am still confused on how the boundary is set, for example if I set a=10, x=0.1, then (a/pi)*sin(pi*x/a) - sin(x) gives a positive value, also if I consider the derivative of (a/pi)*sin(pi*x/a), it has a greater slope when it is closer to 0 than sin (x). Also, I was wondering about how you applied the integral boundary in the next line such as where the csc came from. Thank you.

Comment: I have included $()$ around $\sin(\pi/a)$. And $\csc=1/\sin$; I did it just to avoid fractions.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, unfortunately, I still have problems understanding how you solved for when a is large (I have a vague sense that the Taylor series of sin(pi/a) was used) but I don't understand how it was applied to get the result. Also, I do not understand how the extra subtraction term in the middle of the boundary came to be in the last line of equations. Thank you for all of your help

Comment: There is a mistake in the last line. See the edited answer. And I used the Taylor expansion of $x/sin x$.

Comment: thank you for the further explanation, I think I understand how you arrived at the last line, a further question  I have would be regarding the good approximation, would that not mean that the good approximation is 4*pi^2/(6*a^2)*1.85194, where 1.85194 is the integral of sinc(x) between 0 and pi?

Comment: Exactly.${}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

If $a$ is so large, then the bounds of the integral are not far from 0, so you can approximate both numerator and denominator with Maclaurin series expansion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I seem to lack the math to understand how to use Maclaurin series for integration with the numerator and denominator, could you possibly elaborate?